# CDF of two continuous random variables from PDF function

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

So let's say we have a random variable M and it's continuous. Its PDF function is (4x^3)/81 for 0≤x≤3 and 0 for outside of this interval. And let's say we also have another continuous random variable N that depends on M like N = M^2 + 3. How can I plot the joint CDF of M and N?

Comment: By Y at the end, do you mean N? And are you looking for the joint CDF (multidimensional function), or the CDF of the sum or something else?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry for that. Joint CDF indeed, my bad again.

Comment: Your pdf does not integrate to 1.0. It is not pdf

Comment: You're right.I typed stuff just for an example, I'm a newbie sorry. Fixed it now I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stackoverflow won't let me type this joint CDF derivation in because it thinks it is improperly formatted code, but here is an image of it.
[image: CDF Derivation]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

m = np.linspace(0,3,100)
n = np.linspace(3,12,100)
m_mesh,n_mesh = np.meshgrid(m,n)
joint_cdf = np.minimum(m_mesh,np.sqrt(n_mesh-3))**4/81
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(m_mesh, n_mesh, joint_cdf, cmap=cm.coolwarm,linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```

[image: Joint CDF Plot]

Comment: So how do I change the code if I want it to be seperate?

Comment: What do you mean by separate? Two separate single variable CDFs? For M, you have P[M<=m] = m^4/81 (for 0 <= m <= 3) is the CDF. For N, you want P[N<=n] = P[M^2+3<=n] = P[M<=sqrt(n-3)] = (sqrt(n-3))^4/81 = (n-3)^2/81 (for 3 <= n <= 12).